# K-center algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm

I am currently using python to solving k-center algorithm.
When I run my codes its runtime exceeds the limit time(provided by my teacher),I don't quite know the way to improve my code so it can pass the limited runtime.
My code is below:

```
import math

# 1.Import group
# 2.Find the most farthest point in this group.
# 3.reassign the rest points between two center points
# 4.Find the most farthest point from its center point, and make it the newest center point 
# 5.reassign points among all center points
# 6.Repeat 4 and 5 step untill the answer fits the condition

class point():
    def __init__(self,x,y,num,group=[]):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.id = num
        self.group = []

def range_cus(one,two):
    return math.sqrt(math.pow((one.x-two.x),2)+math.pow((one.y-two.y),2))

def reassign(all_points,all_answer):
    for i in range(len(all_answer)):
        all_answer[i].group = []
    for i in range(len(all_points)):
        if all_points[i] not in all_answer:
        min_length = 0
        for j in range(len(all_answer)):
            current_length = range_cus(all_answer[j],all_points[i])
            if min_length == 0:
                min_length = current_length
                current_group = all_answer[j]
            elif current_length < min_length:
                min_length = current_length
                current_group = all_answer[j]
        current_group.group.append(all_points[i])

def search(all_answer,seek_points_number):
    if seek_points_number == 0:
        return 0
    answer_range = 0
    for j in range(len(all_answer)):
        for i in range(len(all_answer[j].group)):
            if range_cus(all_answer[j],all_answer[j].group[i])>answer_range:
                answer_range = range_cus(all_answer[j].group[i],all_answer[j])
                answer_obj = all_answer[j].group[i]
    seek_points_number -= 1
    final_answer.append(answer_obj)
    reassign(group,final_answer)
    search(final_answer,seek_points_number)

info = raw_input().split(',')
info = [int(i) for i in info]
group = []
final_answer = []
for i in range(info[0]):
    x = raw_input().split(',')
    group.append(point(float(x[0]),float(x[1]),i+1))

final_answer.append(group[info[2]-1])
group[info[2]-1].group = [point for point in group if point not in final_answer]

search(final_answer,info[1]-1)
print ",".join([str(answer.id) for answer in final_answer])
```

Please help me examine where should the function be revised to save some runtime.

```
Example input:

10,3,10 #The first number denotes the sets of data.The second denotes the number of answer I want to return.The third denotes the first center point's id.                   
21.00,38.00
26.00,28.00
45.00,62.00
31.00,51.00
39.00,44.00
42.00,39.00
21.00,27.00
28.00,29.00
31.00,60.00
27.00,54.00

Example output

10,7,6
```

Comment: Do you know how close you are to returning the result in the time allowed? You don't say if your code actually produces the correct result - does it? Also, what data are you giving your code to work on?

Comment: There are several data sets.And I passed eleven data sets.The others failed according to the website which said the time "Time Limit Exceed".

Comment: OK you answered the "does it work" question. What about the other two?

Comment: I don't know how close because the website didn't give me the exact time.
And I only have two example data sets which can't tell much because of its small scale.If you still wants,I can edit in the article.

Comment: So you are supposed to duck under a bar that you can't see. You might need to speed up your code by 1% or 1000%. And you don't have access to the first dataset that fails. Good luck with that.

Comment: Yeah.That's the problem.Since I almost fail on half of the data,I think there must be some major problems in my code......Plz help......

Comment: Using your example input I don't get your example output. I get 10,7,10. You will need a much larger dataset to start using e.g. cProfile to find where your existing recursive code could be improved.

Comment: If I were you I would a) write code to on every run generate a load of random points (initially, use random.seed to always generate the same points so results are repeatable) and load them automatically, so you don't have to enter them every run, and b) then use cProfile to see where time is being spent. Yes range_cus will get called a lot, but all that iterating/recursing is where those calls are generated from. Oh, and it looks to me like the reassign() function is something you could call once, at the end, not for every intermediate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save at least some time by simply rewriting the `range_cus` function. As you call this function inside a nested loop, it should to be a good point of attack. Try replacing it with

```
def range_cus(one,two):
    return sqrt((one.x - two.x)**2 + (one.y - two.y)**2)
```

and remember to do `from math import sqrt` at the top of your program. In this version, you get rid of a lot of lookups on the `math` object (`math.`)

Comment: Yeah!Thanks a lot.It help a little.